# jQuery Autocomplete using AJAX didn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I trying to create an autocomplete using AJAX method but it didn't work. I put an alert in AJAX success and autocomplete source function to see where the problem is, and source's alert works. I couldn't find AJAX problem, here's the code:

jQuery:

```
 $("#wopartname").autocomplete({
        source:function(request,response){
            $.ajax({
                url:AjaxWO,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "act":"selectPartName",
                    "name":request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                    alert("AJAX");
                }
            });
        alert("SOURCE");
        },
        minLength:3
    });
```

PHP:

```
function selectPartName(){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $query = "SELECT nama FROM sparepart WHERE nama LIKE '%$name%' ORDER BY nama ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $data[] = array('label' => $fetch['nama'],'value' => $fetch['nama']);
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }else{
        echo "KO";
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have your php code in a function, are you calling that function -> `selectPartName();` after you have defined it? Also, which alert works, the `alert("AJAX");`, the `alert("SOURCE");` or both?

Comment: @Sean alert("SOURCE"); Works. Yup, i call the function using data "act".

Comment: What does response(data) do?

Comment: So if `alert("SOURCE");` works, but not `alert("AJAX");`, your source ajax is not returning success. Have you defined `AjaxWO`, and does it accurately point to your php file/code? Also, instead of `alert("AJAX");` in source success, try `console.log(data)`, and check your browser's console to see what is returned.

Comment: @PhilipG it is the jquery autocomplete source function response callback -> http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Thank you @Sean it's solved, i put AJAX type as "POST" and autocomplete works.

Answer (score 0):

I declare AJAX type as "POST" and it works.

```
$("#wopartname").autocomplete({
    source:function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
            url:AjaxWO,
            type:"POST",//<===
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "act":"selectPartName",
                "name":request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength:3
});
```